# Setting and fetching cookie using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

I have tried setting a cookie as:

```
 var cookievalue='ABC';
   document.cookie="name=" + cookievalue;
```

After that, i have tried reading a cookie on a next page. Like

```
var allcookies = document.cookie;
   alert( allcookies );
```

Now a problem is the alert box comes to be empty. Please help is it possible to set a cookie on page A suppose and read a cookie on a next page B like the above.

Comment: Could you please look at documentation on how to set cookie using document.cookie. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie
I think the issue might be something to do with one of the cookie attributes!

Comment: Also read about the path and same origin in the docs, take a look at the domains of Page A and Page B, I bet the cookie is not there for being in a different domain/subdomain.